# PHP postgreSql cannot display results

Tags: php, postgresql

Please can someone help me with this I cant find very much information on this problem.

I am connecting fine to PostgreSql database but when I look through the array and display nothing is being displayed, however the exact amount of rows are being displayed s oi know the connection/query are the right syntax, must be the variables syntax but ive tried everything I can find to make it work, any ideas?

```
<?php
pg_connect("host=******** port=**** dbname=****** user=***** password=********") or die("Couldn't Connect"); // Connect to the Database
$query = "SELECT * FROM phones";
$query = pg_query($query);
while($row = pg_fetch_array($query))
{

echo "Model: ".$row['Model']."<br />";
echo "OS: ".$row['OS']."<br />";
echo "Description: ".$row['Description']."<br /><br />";
}
?>
```

Thank you in advance for any help

Comment: Try to dump the whole row first - most probably the result set doesn't have indices named 'Model', 'OS', etc. In that vein - using `select * from` is a bad practice.

Comment: Turns out it was the array indexes they were all lowercase, It worked on my local SQL server didn't even think to change them!!

Answer (score 1):

Try to use pg_last_error();

```
<?php
  $dbconn = pg_connect("dbname=publisher") or die("Could not connect");

  // Query that fails
  $res = pg_query($dbconn, "select * from doesnotexist");
  
  echo pg_last_error($dbconn);
?>
```

https://www.php.net/pg_last_error

Answer (score -1):

Try `pg_fetch_assoc` instead of `pg_fetch_array`, it might work. It works for MySQL.